# List item can't be added from a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am practicing on networking using c#, everything's great so far
I had a situation with a client/serv app where i was trying to send and receive a message
and add the message in a ListBox in the server app.
But after sending the message from the client, it shows me an error (cross-thread operation not valid) and i can't add the message to the list from another Thread
Here's the code :

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread serverListen = new Thread(bufferHandlerThread);
        serverListen.Start();
    }
    private void bufferHandlerThread()
    {
        UdpClient server = new UdpClient(6661);
        while (true)
        {
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            byte[] buffer = server.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            string receivedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            string toAdd = RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() + " <-> " + receivedData;
            dataList.Items.Add(toAdd); // Here the exception.
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you add dataList definition?

Comment: Search for this error, there are a million posts on this

Comment: Unless there is a compelling reason, you should not be working with `Thread` objects directly but using `Task` objects instead.

Comment: What is the list _for_ exactly?

Comment: I searched brother and found only answers who that give direct solution, but i want to understand why, if someone can advice me a book i'd really appreciate. I'm familiar with programming concepts but new to c# so i found out really a big bunch of new stuff.

Comment: @mjwills When i send a string from the client, it adds it to the List in the server

Comment: But _why_ - what are you going to _do_ with that list?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following methods.

```
public static void AddListItemThreadSafe<TControl>(this TControl @this, Action action)  where TControl : ListBox
{
    if (@this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        @this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            dataList.Items.Add(toAdd);

            action(); 
        });
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

Comment: **While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer brother, and i agree with you @AbhishekDutt.. 
If you can advice me with good books for c# i'd appreciate it really.

Comment: This actually worked, i appreciate

Comment: @C0pp3r - This is a bad solution for you specific problem. It's a half-and-half answer.

Comment: @C0pp3r - Redneck is a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
dataList.Items.Add(toAdd);
```

With:

```
Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    dataList.Items.Add(toAdd);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for help brother,
but it says
"Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type" CS1660